# How to implement openID using openid4java in GSP

Tags: grails, servlets, groovy, openid, gsp

How to build openID ReturnURL in gsp??

```
Define a ReturnURL

This is the endpoint where your webapp will receive and process the authentication responses from the OpenID Provider.

    String _returnURL = "http://example.com/openid";
```

Reference:http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/wiki/QuickStart

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have grails.serverURL set appropriately in your config.groovy file you can use the createLink tag with absolute set to true:

```
grails.serverURL = "http://example.com"

String _returnURL = createLink(controller:'openid', action:'handleReturn', absolute:true)

// _returnURL -> http://example.com/appname/openid/handleReturn
```